# Xamarin Android (VS2017) error wih style

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using `Visual Studio 2017 RC`. I started to use it because deploying an Android app with `Visual Studio 2015` was frustrating.

I premise my app was working fine. In a page I use a style for a `BoxView`. The style is define in the **App.xaml** as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Application
    x:Class="myApp.App"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="WarmGreyLine" TargetType="BoxView">
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Fill" />
                <Setter Property="Color" Value="#EEE9E5" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,10" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and in a XAML page I call this style (for two boxview) as

```
<BoxView Style="{StaticResource WarmGreyLine}" />
```

With this line the app goes in error as following image:

[image: Error]

Is this a bug or my fault? Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK the break mode is nothing else than some Break Point. So - IMHO - this is not a bug, it's a feature ;D ... Just kidding, it's no mistake

Comment: Thanks! :) Then is it a bug? or the bug is me?